# Incorrect integer value for a column

Tags: php, mysql

When I submit `null` in `center_id` (not an auto increment column) in single quotes it give me the 
error incorrect integer value for column `center_id` and when I write only the variable like this

```
center_id = $center_id
```

it gives a mysql error.
Please tell me what I am doing wrong with it or suggest something.
Below is my query.

```
Insert into parent_details set center_id='$center_id',name='$name',pin='$pin'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NULL is without quotes, also check whether your column has attribute `not null` in which case it wont accept NULL values.

Comment: What is data type of center_id?

Comment: If `center_id` is an `int` datatype, you don't need to put the value in quotes.

Comment: Could you share the actual php code that you're using and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Center_id data type is int and allowed as null(default null)

Comment: syntax error @I can Has cheezburger

Comment: Incorrect integer value comes when I upload it on server

Answer (score 2):

Numbers and `null`s should not be quoted, strings should. Additionally, your syntax for inserting is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO parent_details (center_id, name, pin)
VALUES ($center_id, '$name', $pin)
```

Comment: when i not quote it out it gives me the error you have error in your mysql syntax on line 1 near pin................

Answer (score 0):

field `center_id` data type is `int` but you may inserted string or special characters because of that is giving above error use below code try to insert integer to `center_id` column

```
insert into parent_details (center_id,name,pin) VALUES ($center_id, $name, $pin)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using prepared statements you shouldn't have this problem in the first place:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('Insert into parent_details 
    set center_id=:center, name=:name, pin=:pin');

$stmt->execute([
    ':center' => null,
    ':name' => 'foo',
    ':pin' => 'bar',
]);
```